# Is it good to put version information into environment variables for include paths to third party libraries?

Tags: c++, build-process, environment-variables

When you are setting up a project to compile in C++, be it VS or make, what is the best practice for setting up environment variables which are used in include paths for third party libraries? Do you include the version number in the variable? i.e.
THIRD_PARTY_LIB_3_1_1=c:\libraries\thirdparty\3.1.1

and then have $(THIRD_PARTY_LIB_3_1_1)\include in your include path

or
THIRD_PARTY_LIB=c:\libraries\thirdparty\3.1.1
and then have $(THIRD_PARTY_LIB)\include in your include path

The benefit of having the version number, is that you know what version you are supposed to be pointing to, the down side is that when you change versions, you have to update all of your project/make files.

The main problem I see in not having version numbers in the environment variable is that it is not explicit, and if you have two projects which use different versions, it becomes a maintenance nightmare and reproducing a build is nearly impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

You should think about it in terms of how the build system would use that information to change its behavior.  It won't act any differently whether you name it one or the other, then its just making more work (and possibly confusion) for yourself.

If a single build needs to include multiple versions of the same `THIRD_PARTY_LIBRARY`, then you would have to differentiate.  Otherwise, when your project specific code specifies the path, that should be clear enough.

> The benefit of having the version number, is that you know what
>   version you are supposed to be pointing to, the down side is that when
>   you change versions, you have to update all of your project/make
>   files.

If someone changed the path and not the variable name, would the path or the variable name be correct?  It is kind of a silly thought, isn't it?  When someone else doesn't change the variable name and you are the one trying to figure out why something is breaking, you'll regret that too.

> The main problem I see in not having version numbers in the
>   environment variable is that it is not explicit, and if you have two
>   projects which use different versions, it becomes a maintenance
>   nightmare and reproducing a build is nearly impossible.

Build files and 3rd party libraries should be in source control.  Your build system should document all of these things when making release builds.  Usually you want your build system to be able to do a full checkout of the code base to ensure the build is correct.  As a side effect of this, it should also know the revision numbers.

My experience is that environment variables are problematic to rely on, and increasingly so the more specific they are.  Many times you need them, so I can't and won't tell you that it's wrong to use them.  You can only have one top level source path environment variable though.  If your build system can use paths based off that, that is only a single place it will fail.  If you have one for every single library, you increase the points of failure.

Comment: Would would the alternative to environment variables be? The problem with hardcoding the path to libraries and include files is that if you make a change, you have to go through all of your projects to change the settings.

Comment: @bpeikes Using relative paths is one option. It's OK to have hard coded paths that are *project* specific.  Different people on different machines shouldn't have to mess with these things though.  I prefer to use CMake to solve this problem, it simplify things a lot.  With CMake, if you need environment variables they are rendered at configuration time, not every build.  This allows you to have two working versions of a project on the same system.